# Slight difference in embeddings for same document in chromadb

Tags: langchain, chromadb, openaiembeddings

I have created a chromadb with `OpenAIEmbeddings(model='text-embedding-ada-002', show_progress_bar=True,chunk_size=20)`
I took a document from the DB and using `.get()` I got its embeddings.

I also calculated embeddings using same class and `.embed_query()`

I subtracted and then `.sum()` and got a difference of `0.0001654693725411943`.

I would expect a much smaller difference if not `0`

Any explanations?

P.S. everything is done via Langchain (i understand it effectively wraps around chromadb and OpenAI API)